# Iscroll4 , menu in #scroller can't scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, iscroll4, iscroll

I have a menu in the `#scroller` inside the `#wrapper` , it should able to scroll/move the `#scroller` div by using jquery+css `transform:translate`,and `css transition`.

After I installed `iscroll4` plugin, when I click it , it skipps my transition animation,and jumps to the location. If I put my menu outside the `#wrapper`, I can scroll the `#scroller` with my css transition again.

CSS Transition is the smoothest way to scroll through a page.Therefore **I DON'T want** to use the `scrollto` javascript function in iscroll, but to trigger css transition function in my own script.

Also I think the scrolling of the page is not as smooth as the default scrolling of the browser.
How to make iscroll scroll more smoother?

Comment: What is you code? Could you provide a fiddle?